# M Language - Divide by the MAX() of a field

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I would like to add a custom column C in my Power BI query (meaning M language, not DAX) so that each value of column B gets divided by the MAX() of column A.

Can't make this work:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [B] / List.Max([Total Score]))
```

I get the error:

> We cannot convert the value null to type List

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [B] / List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Total Score]))`